# Como elimino estas líneas por defecto?

Tags: java, netbeans, clase, consola, click

Como puedo eliminar estas dos líneas que aparecen por defecto al crear una clase, es un poco tedioso eliminarlas de cada clase entonces hay alguna forma para que no vuelvan a aparecer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: agrega el IDE que estas usando, si hay un problema debe ser ahi.

Comment: debería añadir el tag de netbeans

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Incluye las etiquetas apropiadas, y evita el uso de imágenes.

Comment: Hay otra forma de evitarlas, es editando las plantillas que usa NetBeans para crearlas, tiene que ir a "tools/templates", esto te abre una ventana, donde seleccionas "java/java Class", luego le das al botón "Open in Editor", y se abrirá la plantilla en cuestión, solo queda editarla para que cada vez que crees una clase, esté formateada a tu gusto, antes de hacer cualquier modificación, has una copia de respaldo, en caso de que algo salga mal...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**properties>> liscence headers**

En netbeans 16. Haciendo click derecho sobre el proyecto.Después seleccionar properties y ,finalmente, liscence headers.

Hay varias licencias , además puede agregar una . Lo que hago es hacer una vacía y usarla por defecto .
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]